# macOS Monterey firewall off but cannot access port

Tags: network, firewall, docker

I have a PostgreSQL database which is being deployed using docker, basically I'm exposing the port 5432 on my local machine, my firewall is turned off and I'm trying to log into the database from a remote machine using `psql` client with the public-ip-address as host. The connection hangs which is a typical a sign of firewall issues. I don't understand why the port is being blocked even though my firewall is off.

Comment: If you connect to the port locally, does it work? Is there anything helpful in the log files?

Comment: yes it works, all fine.

Comment: all I get is a connection timeout for the logs, nothing really useful there. I have even tried to turn on the firewall and allow all connections to the docker app but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the remote machine on the same network? Could it be that PostgreSQL is listening on the loopback interface (`lo0`)? To check, run `netstat -ln -f inet | grep 5432`, if you see `127.0.0.1.5432`, the port is only accessible locally.

Comment: How do I check if the remote machine is on the same network? Essentially I ssh into the remote machine, but not sure how to check if is the same network.

Comment: the weird thing is that you command returns nothing, however `docker ps` returns that `0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp` and `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres` works fine when logging in locally.

Comment: I was more wondering about the logs on server side, not the error the client gets.

Comment: Also, isn‘t docker just running a VM on macOS?

Comment: ok I checked and don't get any logs on the server side, guess the connection is being blocked by the firewall and does not even arrive at Postgres. I believe docker runs on a VM both on macOS and Windows yes.